# Icon for button not showing when app is running in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

My problem is that in my QML app I have a menu bar button and I want to show the icon on the left and text on the right so that the text is hidden when I menu is contracted and only the icon is showing but when I add the icon to the button it is visible in the Qt Quick Designer but when I run the app the icon is not visible at all.

Here is the code for my main QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: main_frame
        color: "#282c34"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: menu_frame
            width: 56
            color: "#21252b"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            Button {
                id: menu_button
                text: "Hide"
                icon.name: "menu_icon"
                icon.source: "icons/menu.png"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                leftPadding: 17
                checkable: false
                autoExclusive: false
                checked: false
                font.family: "Times New Roman"
                display: AbstractButton.TextBesideIcon
                highlighted: false
                autoRepeat: false
                flat: false
                anchors.leftMargin: 0
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
                anchors.topMargin: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks in the designer:
[image]

Here is how it looks when I run the app:
[image]

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but it may be that the icon file is not integrated in the app's resources...

Comment: another shot in the dark from me ;-) you should not have to use `icon.name` at the same time as `icon.source` (and I would expect `qrc://` for the source)

Comment: Thank you both this worked I used QRC to display my icon on the button if you like you can upload it as an answer

Comment: You can actually also answer yourself, since you know exactly what was wrong